# The arrows does not showing in react slick with 4 and more photos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, react-slick

I'm trying to get the next and previous arrows to show up when I have 4 and more photos on react-slick, but they are not appearing. It's working fine with 3 or fewer photos.

Here is the link of code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/wyyrl6zz3l

Comment: seems to be working fine. The arrows come when I add more images to the example.https://codesandbox.io/s/woqj1z2nq8

Comment: Oooh I had only 4photos, not 5 that's because it was not worked

Comment: Can you tell me what is the exact issue you're facing? From what I can see, if the number of images is more than 4 it shows arrows to the left and right.

Answer (score 18):

its work for me CSS changes

```
.slick-prev {
  left: 3% !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slick-next {
  right: 3% !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is all about the number of slides vs the slidesToShow setting. In your example, you only had 4 slides and it was set to show 4 slides at a time; therefore no arrows are needed.

Set slidesToShow lower than the number of slides, i.e. 1 at a time, and the component responds accordingly.

```
render() {
var settings = {
  dots: true,
  slidesToShow: 1, //if this is less than # of slides, arrows and dots will appear
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/q9o85r7xz6

Answer (score 2):

From the doc, you can write your custom arrows

```js
function SampleNextArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "red" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}
```

```js
function SamplePrevArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "green" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}
```

Then add them to the settings

```js
const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />
    };
```

Check [here](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-arrows) the documentation.

> One important note is if you are using react material do not change `style` to `sx` otherways it wont show up, here is how it should be

```js
function SampleNextArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props
  return (
    <Box
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: 'block', background: 'red' }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import these two files before your custom style files.
The only problem is the above two files overwrite
your custom style:

```
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

Then get the class by inspecting the element and working in your stylesheet
It is working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Give color to these two external classes to show the previous and next buttons.

```css
.slick-prev:before,.slick-next:before {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this Css to show arrow icon.

```css
.slick-slider.slick-initialized {
  width: 100vw;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-prev {
  background: black;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-next {
  background: black;
}
```